# Como hacer una consulta y obtener varios valores y Conteo con linq (ASP.NET MVC 5)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, linq-to-sql

Por ejemplo Tengo una lista de incidencias la cual tiene varios tipos de incidencias y fecha de creación por usuarios, quiero obtener el resultado de Cuantas Incidencias se reportaron por día, Que cantidad Mostrando el Nombre de la incidencia y Cuantos usuarios reportaron incidencias divido en tipos de incidencias.

Por ejemplo tengo este código pero solo puedo mostrar el resultado Cuantas Incidencias por Día

`var Lista_DxD = (from lista in db.Inconvenientes_Remoto.Where(m => m.Fecha_Inconveniente >= Fecha_Ini && m.Fecha_Inconveniente <= Fecha_Final) group lista by lista.Fecha_Inconveniente.Day into g select  new { listaDXD = g.Key, conteo = g.Count() }).ToList();`

Seria una tabla como esta que quiero:

Tipo de Inc  ------------  Cantidad ------------- Día
Avería De internet  ----  5  ---------------  ---- -1
Avería De Energía -----13  ---------------  ---- 2

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: Hola, puede editar la pregunta añadiendo unos ejemplo de la tabla original, unos cuantos datos seria bueno para entender mejor lo que se necesita.